# How do I get the "What I follow" Feed using Chatter REST API?

Tags: rest-api, chatter, chatter-feed

This seems like the most relevant type of feed to be exposed in Chatter REST API, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do it.

[image: what I follow feed]

What I need is the endpoint (if there is one) or the SOQL to **get a user's "What I Follow" chatter feed**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in the [News Feed](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resource_feeds_news.htm) resource. The great part about the Chatter API is that it is self-describing; if you go into the [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/), go to the REST Explorer, and start drilling down, you'll eventually find what you want. Specifically, What I Follow is found in:

```
/services/data/v42.0/chatter/feeds/news/me/feed-elements
```

By using the REST Explorer, you can see other types of feeds you can use:

[image: News Feeds REST API]